# kSoap2 HttpTransportSE does not work with api11 and higher apis

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am currently devoloping and app which is using ksoap2 web service.
I am using "ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

Here is my problem.

I can succesfuly receive data on api10 and lower versions. (*on my
phone and virtual machines)

But when ı tested my app on Android Virtual machines which is api 11
and higher versions.

HttpTransportSE does not work.

my codes;(not all of)

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvol= new
SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
HttpTransportSE setConn = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

     try {
     setConn.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvol);
    }
     catch{Exception e)
    {
          return null;
    }
```

""" `setConn.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvol);` """ always falls to catch on
api 11 av machines.

what i am missing?
Thanks allready.

edit: (Full code respond)

```
public List<HashMap<String, String>> duyurulariListeOlarakGetir() {
        SoapObject istek = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        istek.addProperty("user", "123");
        istek.addProperty("pass", "123");
        istek.addProperty("appID", "1");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapZarf = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapZarf.dotNet = true;
        soapZarf.setOutputSoapObject(istek);

        HttpTransportSE baglantıKur = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {

            baglantıKur.debug=true;
            baglantıKur.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapZarf);

            SoapObject sonuclar = (SoapObject) soapZarf.getResponse();

            int totalCount = sonuclar.getPropertyCount();
            if (totalCount > 0) {
                for (int detailCount = 0; detailCount < totalCount; detailCount++) {

                    SoapObject pojoSoap = (SoapObject) sonuclar.getProperty(detailCount);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("duyuruID", pojoSoap.getProperty("duyuruID").toString());
                    map.put("duyuruMetin", pojoSoap.getProperty("duyuruMetin").toString());
                    map.put("duyuruSaat", pojoSoap.getProperty("duyuruSaat").toString());
                    map.put("duyuruBaslik", pojoSoap.getProperty("duyuruBaslik").toString());
                    map.put("duyuruTarih", pojoSoap.getProperty("duyuruTarih").toString());
                    map.put("kurumID", pojoSoap.getProperty("duyuruSilindi").toString());
                    map.put("uygulamaID", pojoSoap.getProperty("duyuruSilindi").toString());
                    map.put("duyuruSilindi", pojoSoap.getProperty("duyuruSilindi").toString());

                    fillMaps.add(map);
                }
            } else
                return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("duyuruID", "");
            map.put("duyuruMetin", "Bağlantı kurulamadı");
            map.put("duyuruSaat", "Bağlantı kurulamadı");
            map.put("duyuruBaslik", "Bağlantı kurulamadı");
            map.put("duyuruTarih", "Bağlantı kurulamadı");
            map.put("kurumID", "Bağlantı kurulamadı");
            map.put("uygulamaID","Bağlantı kurulamadı");
            map.put("duyuruSilindi", "Bağlantı kurulamadı");

            fillMaps.add(map);
            return fillMaps;
        }
        return fillMaps;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is some sort of bug as i had also experienced this problem with my app running on ICS. If i'm not mistaken then it happens when you try to communicate with an SSL enabled server, rite? Well, eventually i had to switch to Json to resolve this and I'm very happy with this move as its more fast and easier to deal with

Comment: ı have to use kSoap because we are devoloping same app for Iphone and we want to use same web service.

Comment: ı added full code but this codes works perfectly on under api version 10

Comment: Is your webservice in *ASP.NET*? because you can support both **xml** and **json** simultaneously just be changing a little in your **web.config**. My service is also supporting both and its working just perfect

Comment: @Waqas 
can you explain more?

Comment: awesome... so if you want, you may simply enable support for Json too. Ask me if you need help with this :)

Comment: I mean Asp.NET webservices can support Json string response too. All you need to do is to add a **handler** in your web.config and decorate your service code file **[ScriptService]** attribute and you are done. Afterwards, if user request for xml in header of request, then the service will respond with xml/SOAP data. But if user mentions json in request header then Json string will be responded

Comment: I am using SOAP service in my iOS app with no problem, in case you want to use same web service for both Android and iOS, what @Waqas says might be useful -if I didn't misunderstand.

Comment: Just for an overview, read this article: **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-2-0-with-a-jQu** It demonstrate both SOAP and Json responses from a single webservice. Personally, I would recommend to use Json as it requires less data to transfer the same information compared to SOAP, its simple, easy to grip and supported natively in Android. Moreover, you can read **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851117/scriptmethodresponseformat-responseformat-json** and **http://encosia.com/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/**

Comment: @Waqas i have created a web service like your frist link. But how i create ı query for .net web service using json?

Comment: first, are you able to see xml response and json response from same web-service in browser?

Comment: check out this link http://www.filedropper.com/jsondemo I've created a demo project in which I'm using your web-service to show how you can download data in json and recreate the objects using Gson. Ask me if you need any clarification or further help. Good luck :)

Comment: ohh yeah, moreover, if you want, you may actually tweak your web service a little to use even single method to offer both json and xml simultaneously (no need to write *TestJSON* and *TestXML*, just use *Test*). It will be helpful to keep your web service same (no duplicate methods)

Comment: @Waqas , Thank you a lot.your answers are very precious for me.  and lastly i realy don't get consept of "single method to offer both json and xml simultaneously" this two method have diffirent return type. json method returns String. xlm method returns Entity[] array.

Comment: Even if you remove the return type attribute at top of method and keep a single method (instead of two), it will still work. The return type is to restrict the response type, but we may let it depend on request type too - making it more dynamic to adapt the situation. Paste your web service code at pastebin.com and I'll modify it a little to show you an example  :)

Comment: @Waqas THANKS A LOT; http://pastebin.com/wL6Z9g7r

Comment: you are welcome. This service http://pastebin.com/swhd8eKi will serve both xml and json response depending on the request type. So you can see that i have a uniform method to serve both. Simply update your existing web-services with **ScriptService** and you are good to go. Good luck :)

Comment: @Waqas, I'm trying to supply what you explained here in iOS, using a similar of this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968042/passing-parameters-to-a-json-web-service-in-objective-c // however, I'm unable to make it work so far. do you have any clue how to make it work in iOS (above 5.0)

Comment: sorry, I'm not an iOS developer, but i can help you with .NET part where your webservice is involved. See my answer :)

Comment: or perhaps post your webservice code online so i can see any anomalies...

Comment: @Waqas thanks, I've solved and posted the solution to related question. now I have a problem with returning data. NSJSONSerialization wants pure string with json objects but returning value starts with "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" and ends with "</string>". i already remove these strings and clean the response but it's not a solution really I think. what do you think I should do in order to remove xml headers in my web service?

Comment: it only shows the xml stuff if you request through asmx webpage (by clicking the method name). But if you make request with json as header params, then it shouldnt include the xml stuff. Did you log the response of webmethod in phone? what exactly it returns?

Comment: @Waqas, please see the code and response: http://pastebin.com/9TraWRTE

Comment: I think your request is not valid for Json. It should be `[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Comment: @Waqas, that caused an error like this: http://jsfiddle.net/confeng/wRP3H/

Comment: actually now its working fine. but the error is due to invalid argument. are you passing the correct parameter name as required by your web-service? paste your webservice code too. Moreover, use http://jsonlint.com/ to format and read json strings for your own readability

Comment: if `sorgu=0` is your input parameter for web method then as a valid json parameter it should be `{"sorgu": 0}`

Comment: @Waqas thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: you're welcome. happy jsonizing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to the fact that in apis 11 and above accesing the net in Main thread is not allowed you may have to use ASYNC task.. I had an app which used JSON objects to get data , i had initially coded it simply in the onCreate (very small code) .. it worked fine on my phone.. but when i tried it on my tablet (ICS) it gave me errors, in the debug i saw an exception , when i googled it I found out the problem , hope it helps you, cheers!