# $.ajax get, mvc 3 jsonresult - undefined result

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC 3 jsonresult controller that returns a JSON string which contains the regions associated with a specific country, code below:

```
    public JsonResult getRegions(int countryID)
    {
        var regions = from r in db.Regions where r.CountryID == countryID select r;

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("[");
        foreach (Region region in regions)
            //builder.AppendFormat("{0}, \"{1}\"", "RegionID: " + region.RegionID, "RegionName: " + region.RegionName);                
            builder.Append("{ RegionID: " + region.RegionID + ", RegionName: " + region.RegionName + "},"); 
        //var result = builder.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', ' ' }) + "]";            
        builder = builder.Append("]");

        var result = builder.Replace(",]", "]");

        return Json(result.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This returns a JSON formatted string, lets assume the Country Selected was Kenya, the output string looks as follows:

```
    [{ RegionID: 1, RegionName: Nairobi Region},{ RegionID: 3, RegionName: Coast Region}]
```

I have a javascript that passes the id for the country to the controller to get the regions, which i eventually want to use to populate a new dropdownlist. My javascript looks as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$("#CountryID").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajaxcalls/getregions",
        data: "countryID=" + $("#CountryID :selected").val(),
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var options = ("#regions");
            $.each(result, function (item) {
                alert(item.RegionID + " " + item.RegionName);
            });
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(error + " " + req);
        }
    });
});
    });
```

But the alert that pops up says:

> undefined undefined.

Comment: Please provide more information regarding the response from the server, undefined undefined could show when you are trying to convert an object into a string.

Comment: I only noticed the undefined from the altert message, it is not a server response i don't believe.

Answer (score 3):

I'd highly recommend using a JSON serializer to build a JSON string, something like [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), [`Json.NET's Serializer`](http://json.codeplex.com/) or [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx). This will make the process of creating JSON less prone to errors and save you the effort of hand-rolling one :)

It looks as though the JSON that you are building is not valid JSON: each key should be double-quoted, as should each string value.

In addition, the function passed to `$.each` takes two arguments, index and value, so the `$.each` call inside of `success` function should be

```
$.each(result, function (index, item) {
    alert(item.RegionID + " " + item.RegionName);
});
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more on client side stuff? I think he is not extracting the data part using data.d. Would love to have your comments on that :)

Comment: @Rohan - In MVC, the response is not wrapped in the `d` object as it is in ASP.NET web services and page methods. As the OP is using jQuery and the datatype is set to `json`, jQuery will parse the response (after checking that it is "safe" json) into a JavaScript data structure that can then be worked with.

Comment: I didn't really want to use someone else's serializer because then i will never learn exactly how to create my own json strings. but it seems this will be the path i have to go.

Comment: @RobinCurtis: Its good, but then why reinvent the wheel? :) and I would want to add one more point in case you use JavaScriptSerializer is that you have to set the maxJsonLength property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx

Comment: @Robin - Agree with Rohan here, it's not worth expending the effort to reinvent the whell, in my opinion. The important point is that you understand the structure of json :)

Answer (score 0):

use result.d and the get the actual data. What does firebug say?

You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837865/eval-response-d-in-jquery-ajax) too.

Comment: I ended up just changing the ouput of the controller to use .ToList() and mvc seemed to have serialized it for me. thanks for all the responses guys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, null, function (countryString) {
        //countryString es the data returned from de action method.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your error to look like this

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
alert(errorThrown);
}
```

and use IISExpress - in VS build in web server these properties not being generated.

Good luck